# Unable to retrieve values using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

My problem is that i want to take entities value of a Linq Resultant. Below is my method

My Datalayer Method:

```
private static readonly Func<DataContext, String, String, IQueryable<AuthenticateUserResult> > AuthenticateUser__impl= CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext context, String username, String password) => 
(   from u in context.GetTable<Yantriki.MeriRanchi.Web.UI.Core.User>()
    where ((u.UserName == username)
         && (u.Password == password)
         && (u.IsActive == true))
    select new AuthenticateUserResult 
    {
        MemberId = u.MemberId,
        Email = u.Email,
        Name = u.Name,
        Role = u.Role,
        UserName = u.UserName
    }));
```

Above code is generated by Visual Linq Designer. Now I am returning the  result to UI layer using the method below:

```
   public static IQueryable AuthenticateUser(User user)
        {
            var db = new MeriRanchiDataContext();
            return MeriRanchiQueries.AuthenticateUser(db, user.UserName, user.Password);
        }
```

At my UI layer I need values stored in the entities, MemberId, Email, Name so that I can set it to session. SO what will be expression for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the generic `IQueryable<AuthenticateUserResult>` instead of the non-generic `IQueryable`.

Comment: I did that but i was getting null reference exception while fetching entities.

Comment: The null reference exception has nothing to do with the return type.

Comment: not with return type...it appeared when i was applying lambda expression to fetch result.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am answering my own question as I got its solution and thinking it might help other facing the same issue.

What i did?

1. I revert back the return type to `IQueryable<AuthenticateUserResult>`
2. Added SingleOrDefault() as extension.
3. Used the code below

---

```
var userResults =
    MeriRanchiDataManager.AuthenticateUser(user).SingleOrDefault();

Session["UserName"] =userResults.MemberId;
Session["Email"] = userResults.Email;
Session["Role"] = userResults.Role.ToString();
Session["MemberId"] = userResults.MemberId.ToString();
Session["Name"] = userResults.Name;
```